# can I use an old bundle identifier in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

Good morning, I had an old bundle identifier com.a.b, but now I create a new project with the same bundle identifier com.a.b, Xcode tells me I should change it, how can I use com.a.b in this new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not. A bundle identifier is a unique ID in the Apple Developer portal.
If I define one in my account, it will be blocked for you as well. 
Even if I delete mine, it will not be released.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I mean I have the bundle identifier "com.a.b" in project A , then I delete project A, and create a project B , I want my project B uses the bundle identifier "com.a.b", is there anything I can do to make it happy? thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If I get you right, there is probably nothing you need to do on the Apple Developer portal (unless your app entitlements change).  
But the new app will overwrite the old on devices, as the bundle identifier is the unique ID on the device.  
I would worry about the user experience, though ...

Comment: thanks for your answer ! , finally I change my bundle identifier , 